# CodeWars - javascript - Multiples of 3 or 5 recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm currently training on codewars, and today was multiples of 3 and 5.
I tried with a casual solution using reduce + ternary, and it worked.

I then tried to solve it with recusrive function.
Instructions are as follow :

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Finish the solution so that it returns the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in. Additionally, if the number is negative, return 0 (for languages that do have them).

Link is here

https://www.codewars.com/kata/514b92a657cdc65150000006

Here is my solution :

```
let res = 0

function solution(n){
    if(n - 1 <= 0) {
    return 0
  }
  if((n - 1) % 3 > 0) {
    if((n - 1) % 5 > 0) {
        return solution(n - 1, res)
    } else {
        res += n - 1
        solution(n - 1, res)
    }
  } else {
    res += n - 1
    solution(n - 1, res)
  }
  return res
}
```

It works on my computer but fails on codewars attemps, giving extravagant results, such as solution(6) = 9283  whereas on my computer 8 (correct answer)

Also, I got the maximum call stack exceeded on codewars for 9513, but not on my computer.

Ideas anyone ?

Comment: Your `solution` method is defined to take a single parameters, but you pass two arguments.

Comment: Yes, 8, sorry , it's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function solution(number) {
  // Base case: return 0 if the number is negative
  if (number < 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Recursive case: if the number is a multiple of 3 or 5, add it to the sum of
  // the multiples of 3 or 5 below it, otherwise just return the sum of the
  // multiples of 3 or 5 below it
  return (number % 3 === 0 || number % 5 === 0)
    ? number + solution(number - 1)
    : solution(number - 1);
}
```

Comment: thank you, this does the job and indeed matches the recursive requirements, nevertheless, it does the same on codewars sandbox, it puts the same error as for my function, giving either strange results such as "expected 33 to equal 23", and also has some maximum stack call errors

Comment: That's simply an off-by-one error, I imagine.  `10` is a multiple of `5`, so if you add all the appropriate numbers up-to-and-including-`10`, you will get `33`, when you wanted all the appropriate numbers up-to-but-NOT-including-`10`.  It should be relatively simple to fix.  At most, rename this to `_solution` and write `const solution  = (n) => _solution (n - 1)`.  But there's probably a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the sum of an arithmetic sequence to do this without iterating, so O(1).

[image]
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

```js
const input = 10

function sum35(num){
  num = num - 1
  const lastThree = num - num%3
  const threeQuantity = lastThree/3
  
  const lastFive = num - num%5
  const fiveQuantity = lastFive/5
  
  return getSum(threeQuantity,3,lastThree) + getSum(fiveQuantity, 5, lastFive)
  
  function getSum(n, first, last) {
   return (n/2)*(first + last)
  }
}

console.log(sum35(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining `res` as a global is very likely the problem: its value will be reused for subsequent calls of the function.

Change your function to take `res` as a parameter. If the signature must define only a single parameter, using an inner function would be an idea.

Here's a solution using a nested function, simplifying some of the unnecessary complications and duplications:

```
function solution(n) {
    let res = 0;

    function _solution(n) {
        if(n <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        if(n % 3 != 0 && n % 5 != 0) {
            return _solution(n - 1);
        }

        res += n;
        _solution(n - 1);
        return res;
    }

    return _solution(n - 1);
}
```

But note that this is not a "clean" recursive approach, because the function is actually a closure and has a side-effect: modifying the value of the outside variable `res`. For a proper recursive implementation, see [yanai edri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74675592/112968).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it passes much of the tests, 23 success, for 4 errors , namely : n=56440, n=39455, n=69856, n=87421 . I'm starting to wonder whether it's not a problem with codewars checking system